# Rewriting different URL from one page to another using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to know if there is a way to redirect long URLs to short URLs.

I have an RSS page that will list out a number of news items from my website. The URL format of each item (as per MySQL query) is something like `http://example.com/news.php?id=2`.

On my `news.php` (after being redirected to the news page upon clicking on any news title on the RSS page), there are parameters set to carry along the IDs which looks like `http://example.com/news.php?news=2&view=1&topic=12`.

For SEO purpose, I need to `erase` that dirty query string so that viewers will only see `http://example.com/news.php?id=2` while on the server-side, it actually reads `http://example.com/news.php?news=2&view=1&topic=12`.

I had created an .htaccess file and it is placed inside the `rss` folder (where the rss.php file is located ) and tried several attempts but to no available.

Help me on this.

Comment: You should use: http://example.com/news/2 instead of http://example.com/news.php?id=2

Comment: hi Book Of Zeus..yes, that's right..I'm wrong with that...but i hope the rest of my explanation is enough for you to help me out..any idea?

Comment: and how am i going to achieve your suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I would do:

```
RewriteEngine on

# id + view + topic
# http://www.domain.com/news/1/1/12 will load: /news.php?news=1&view=1&topic=12
RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)(/?)$ /news.php?news=$1&view=$2&topic=$3 [QSA,L,NC]
```

Please this .htaccess in the root folder.

Comment: already tried this but fail.....are you sure we really have to put the L flag on each rule?

Comment: Where did you put the .htaccess file? No you dont need to

Comment: I put it inside root folder of the application,just like you said....not inside the rss folder... and, another thing is, i don't want it to be applied to just a news item, i want it to be applied to any of the news item when clicked..so, it is not always going to be topic=12

Comment: is mod rewrite enable? allowoverride all? View my edited answer.

Comment: yes, mod rewrite and allowoverride are enabled in my Apache because i make redirections with htaccess with different purposes before this and they work fine.....

Comment: This rule does not conflict with any others rules?

Answer (score 2):

Should the parameters be assigned to ($1,$2,$3...etc) instead?

```
 RewriteRule ^news(/?)$ /news.php?news=$1&view=$2&topic=$3 [QSA,L,NC]
```